# How can I create Knife animations in blender?

Tags: animation, graph-editor, dopesheet

I have created a Game-Engine ready setup for exporting a selection of animations to Unity. I am currently in the process of creating, what is meant to be, CSGO style knife animations. Note that I am reasonably familiar with animation in blender (however I am only an intermediate)

My setup currently:
[image]

How should I start? I'd like to know (to begin) how to make just a basic idle, breathing animation. With the complicated structure of blender's set of specialized editors (the graph editor, dope sheet etc...) I find it difficult to know how to start, and after that make it feel immersive and natural. Also I'd like to know if there is more needed in my setup, for example my game is an fps, should I add a camera for a reference view?

If anyone can help me start creating these animations, and show me the steps involved for creating even a simple idle breathing animation using this setup. That'd be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a link to a video how it should look like?

Comment: Would you like the Idle animation, or the whole set of animations I wish to create (or base off of)?

Comment: 3:30-3:45 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-oQT0zXPHU : This is closest to the style of animations I am looking for